# Different kinds of emptiness/negation = different kinds of nothingness? Re: the Kyoto School

Tags: negation, nothingness

The SEP entry on the Kyoto School was updated the other day, and I decided to read through at least some of it. [Here's part of a discussion of the "nothingness" that is central to their reflections](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kyoto-school/#AbsoNothGiviPhilFormForm):

[image]

We've had a few ill-received nothingness-related questions here of late, regarding e.g. [using the definite article with the word "nothing"](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/105815/is-it-correct-to-say-nothing-or-the-nothing) or [a lack of "anything" as inclusive of a lack of "nothing"](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/106069/what-is-the-lack-of-anything-including-nothing). But so I wonder if the presuppositional intuition behind those questions pertains to the intuitions of the Kyoto School or predecessors thereof, like Heidegger (though he was also a contemporary) or Eckhart. And then I wonder if there is a deeper *logico-mathematical* basis for such confusion and seemingly hapless attempts at clarification. **Does differentiating between different kinds of negation, or between things like a graph with no nodes or edges at all vs. a graph with no edges but at least one node (or at least one edge but no nodes at all), help rehabilitate inquiry into "nothingness" as meaningful inquiry, despite the inherent mysteriousness of the act of referring to the (in)act(ion) of not referring to anything?** As if some concepts of nothingness, as based on one or another kind of negation, are meaningless, but other such concepts, based on other such kinds, are *not* so meaningless, despite appearances?

Or consider the various [semantic approaches to category mistakes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-mistakes/#SemaAppr): might these be interpolated into roughly three grades of "nothingness," where a question about "nothingness" can lack one of the three semantic grounds (either meaning, content, or truth-value), or such a question can lack any two of those grounds, with "absolute nothingness" being the "object of inquiry" which is fully lost in mystification insofar as such inquiry lacks all three such grounds? For often enough, the spectacle of mystified queries about "nothingness" *looks like* a category mistake *par excellence*.

---

**Historical caveat:** while going over the above, it occurred to me that Heidegger's place in the philosophy of Nazi Germany might've been reflected by the Kyoto School's place in the philosophy of Hirohito's Japan, i.e. the preoccupation with seemingly reifiable nothingness was a dangerous vortex in Heidegger and the school's minds, something that mirrored the *practical* drive towards mass annihilation that the two background regimes engaged in. Perhaps Nietzsche foresaw this danger himself, and expressed his foreknowledge in his little poesy about looking into the "abyss." (Nietzsche too has been seen as a prelude to Nazism to some extent, fair or unfair as this perception is, and at any rate he is mentioned in the same section of the SEP article about the Kyoto School that I blockquoted above.) So perhaps there is also a concept of ***moral*** (deontic) nothingness in play, here.

Comment: Not sure if the Kyoto school nothing is what Shunyata refers to. It can't be written about if not directly experienced. (Can't be written about if it has)

Comment: @ScottRowe it sure is a hard topic to ask a meaningful question about, by definition no less (I suppose)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heidegger names two types of nothing in his 1949 preface to [*On the Essence of Ground*](https://web.archive.org/web/20151028052521/http://users.clas.ufl.edu/burt/spliceoflife/Heideggerground.pdf) in Pathmarks, p. 97:

> The nothing is the "not" of beings, and is thus being, experienced
> from the perspective of beings. The ontological difference is the
> "not" between beings and being. Yet just as being, as the "not" in
> relation to beings, is by no means a nothing in the sense of a *nihil
> negativum*, so too the difference, as the "not" between beings and
> being, is in no way merely the figment of a distinction made by our
> understanding (*ens rationis*).
>
> That nihilative "not" of the nothing and this nihilative "not" of the
> difference are indeed not identical, yet they are the Same in the
> sense of belonging together in the essential prevailing of the being
> of beings.

There seems to be an interesting analogy in Eugene Thacker's [*Darklife: Negation, Nothingness, and the Will-to-Life in Schopenhauer*](https://parrhesiajournal.org/parrhesia12/parrhesia12_thacker.pdf), p. 11. I.e. Being = Life; both are noumenal, therefore we can know nothing of them. They have the absence of thingness (phenomenality), hence privative: *nihil privativum*.  (Maybe not Schopenhauer's meaning.)  The *nihil negativum* seems to be rather more sketchy in both quotes.  Perhaps it is absence of consciousness, or even the unconscious.

> In response to the Kantian split between Life and the living, and in
> contrast to the post-Kantian ontology of generosity, Schopenhauer opts
> for a negative ontology of life.
>
> However, that life is “nothing” can mean several things. The enigmatic
> last section of *WWR I* bears out some of these meanings. Here
> Schopenhauer makes use of Kant’s distinction between two kinds of
> nothing: the *nihil privativum* or privative nothing, and the *nihil
> negativum* or negative nothing. The former is nothing defined as the
> absence of something (e.g. shadow as absence of light, death as
> absence of life). For Schopenhauer the world is nothing in this
> privative sense as this interplay between Representation and Will; the
> world, with all its subject-object relations, as well as its ongoing
> suffering and boredom, is transitory and ephemeral. By contrast, the
> indifferent Will-to-Life courses through and cuts across it all, all
> the while remaining in itself inaccessible, and “nothing.”

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, directly and indirectly, of Kant's fourfold table of nothingnesses, and connecting it to Heidegger but also Schopenhauer. I normally don't wonder about nothingness that much, but the recent unfortunate questions about it gave me some pause, and I was looking for a point-of-contact with their concerns. Your answer appears to be a place of common ground between me and posters like those, and then the Kyoto School (who I am trying to relate to, while reading the SEP entry on them).

Comment: @KristianBerry You're most welcome.

Comment: "*Things can* be, *and their being is grounded in* nothing's *ability to* noth." - Kenneth Burke

Comment: @ScottRowe Noth is here: "The nothing unveils itself in anxiety—but not as a being. ... The nothing itself does not attract; it is essentially repelling. ... This wholly repelling gesture toward beings that are slipping away as a whole, which is the action of the nothing that closes in on Dasein in anxiety, is the essence of the nothing: nihilation. It is neither an annihilation of beings nor does it spring from a negation. Nihilation will not submit to calculation in terms of annihilation and negation. The nothing itself nihilates."  https://www.beyng.com/pages/en/Pathmarks/Pathmarks.090.html

Comment: "Das Nichts enthüllt sich in der Angst—aber nicht als Seiendes. ... Dieses zieht nicht auf sich, sondern ist wesenhaft abweisend. ... Diese im Ganzen abweisende Verweisung auf das entgleitende Seiende im Ganzen, als welche das Nichts in der Angst das Dasein umdrängt, ist das Wesen des Nichts: die Nichtung. Sie ist weder eine Vernichtung des Seienden, noch entspringt sie einer Verneinung. Die Nichtung läßt sich auch nicht in Vernichtung und Verneinung aufrechnen. Das Nichts selbst nichtet." https://web.archive.org/web/20220115130514id_/https://www.nomos-elibrary.de/10.5771/9783465141839.pdf

Comment: Sounds awfully negative.

Comment: @ScottRowe Yes, but anxiety seems to be a special case in which nothing is tangible, i.e. https://www.beyng.com/pages/en/Pathmarks/Pathmarks.088.html

Comment: He’s actually positive about nothing/Beyng, i.e. “The inventive thinking of beyng does indeed not simply think up a concept; instead, it gains that liberation from mere beings which makes appropriate the determination of thinking on the basis of beyng. ...” (Contributions to Philosophy, §265)

Comment: in a Buddhist kind of way, i.e. “by completely surmounting the base of neither perception-nor-non-perception, a true man enters upon and abides in the cessation of perception and feeling. And his taints are destroyed by his seeing with wisdom. This bhikkhu does not conceive anything, he does not conceive in regard to anything, he does not conceive in any way.” [Sappurisa Sutta, MN 113](https://www.suttas.com/mn-113-sappurisa-sutta-the-true-man.html)

Comment: @ScottRowe So non-conceptualising apprehension, non-identifying, not getting caught up in the beings.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but I find the Heidegger wording impossible to understand, where the Buddhist wording makes sense to me.